# irq_to_desc function failing with IRQ number

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to install an IRQ handler for the IRQ line 43 as below:

```
ret2 = request_irq(irq_no, handle_interrupt, IRQF_SHARED, DEVICE_NAME, &pdev->dev);
```

But I keep on getting rquest_irq failed with -22 which is INVALID input. After looking into the kernel code I could see the function request_threaded_irq() is returning with -EINVAL at the below point:

```
desc = irq_to_desc(irq);
if (!desc) {
    printk(KERN_EMERG "%s:%d\n", __func__, __LINE__);
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

Can any one please help me understanding what could be the reason for the irq_to_desc() function to return NULL? 
I am using Kernel version 4.11 in a mips machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using device tree for your platform? If so, can you check if you have correct `interrupt-controller` entry in it? Usually `irq_to_desc()` fails when it fails to find the corresponding IRQ descriptor to an irq number either from a radix-tree maintained by IRQ subsystem (if `CONFIG_SPARSE_IRQ`is enabled) OR by a simple translation when your irq number (43) is greater than total number of IRQs availabe in system (`NR_IRQS`).

Comment: @vtha thanks. In my kernel CONFIG_SPARSE_IRQ=y. And the Kernel is failing to find the it in the radix tree. Now, here is how my device tree looks like at the moment: 
    / {
    compatible = "abc, xyz";
    #address-cells = <2>;
    #size-cells = <2>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    abc: jasper@8050000000 {
    compatible = "xyz,xyz-abc";
    reg = <0x00 0x20810000 0x0 0x010000>,
    <0x80 0x50000000 0x0 0x40000000>;
    interrupts = <43 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    status = "disabled";
    }

Comment: can you check your interrupt controller driver (`gic` node entry may give you hint where to find interrupt controller driver) that it registered enough number of interrupts?

Comment: @vtha thanks again. I seem to have found the issue here. I was trying to use the interrupt number hard coded in my driver, as in the question. But I have now changed that to the below:
    module_irq = irq_of_parse_and_map(pdev->dev.of_node, 0);
and using module_irq in the request_irq seems to be working. I not getting the -EIVAL anymore, and my interrupt handler is being called as well. 
I think the key here is that you pointed out it is an issue with my dts file and that gave me the valuable clue. 
I am not sure how to accept an answer in this site, I want to accept your response.

Comment: BTW irq_of_parse_and_map() is giving me a totally different mapped IRQ number "18". So just to clarify the reason for failing was I was trying to use hard coded value 43 in the request_irq and it was failing with -EINVAL. When I started using the the return value of irq_of_parse_and_map(), I didn't get -EINVAL and also my dummy interrupt handler is getting called.

Comment: Glad that you figured out the problem. BTW I can just write some description in the answer box, and you may just upvote it or accept it as answer :)

Comment: @vtha :-) yes sure, please post your response as an answer in the answer box and then I think I can accept it, it really helped to focus the investigation on the dts file, cheers

Comment: Cool, I've posted the description, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `irq_to_desc()` can fail if the corresponding IRQ number is not mapped to any allocated IRQ descriptors. IRQ descriptors are stored in a radix tree if `CONFIG_SPARSE_IRQ` kernel config is enabled. Otherwise there is a direct translation between IRQ number and descriptor.

IRQ descriptors are usually allocated when interrupt controller driver is registered. You can refer to the datasheet of the interrupt controller OR the datasheet of the platform which you are using.

You can check if IRQ 43 is valid for your interrupt controller or not. The interrupt controller information can be found from the device-tree node of your device (look for `interrupt-parent` in your device tree node).

Hope this helps.